# Is it possible to create a flex contact form that submits data to salesforce.com as a new lead?

Tags: apache-flex, soap, salesforce

Salesforce.com has their own web-to-lead form that can be used to send leads from a website contact form. But I want to submit leads from a contact form inside a flex application. I can't see anything in the documentation, or on Google about this. Is it possible?

If it is possible, is Flex for Force.com necessary to do this?

Comment: You should be able to do this using the Salesforce.com Developer API: http://developer.force.com/

Comment: Then do you think the Flex for Force.com is not needed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I meant to say that you should be able to access the salesforce.com Developer API from a Flex app to create a new sales lead.  I don't know their API, personally, so am not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Flex developer, but I'll try to answer from a Force.com perspective.

Much like the AJAX toolkit, the Flex toolkit is primarily used to add value to your existing Force.com apps. If you're talking about an app running inside Force.com and you wish it to be pure Flex, then the toolkit would be a fine choice - though hardly a required one.

But since you're talking about web-to-lead that makes me think you're hosting your own Flex app or it's otherwise in another cloud. In this case what Flextras suggested is correct in that all you need is to call the API directly from your Flex app - without having a need (or a place for that matter) for the Flex toolkit.

It uses the Force.com API under the hood - from within Force.com - to talk with Force.com. From there you would simply use Visualforce and Apex to do the job. Outside Force.com you just need the API, unless you're looking for an offline Air app that needs seamless synching.